# ABCD and AECF are two parallelograms and side EF is parallel to AD . suppose AF and DE met at X and BF AND CE AT Y . prove that XY is parallel to AB

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

[image]
 I tried proving it by showing angles exy and eyx equal to edc and ecd respectively but I got no where . Is there any other approach I should consider

Comment: Please edit title and body of the question to make it more readable. You could at least use GeoGebra to make a decent diagram.

Comment: HINT: use [intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem).

Comment: HINT: ...and a [ruler](https://goo.gl/images/XZaiYi).

Answer (score 1):

Because by similarity we obtain: 
$$\frac{FY}{YB}=\frac{EF}{BC}=\frac{EF}{AD}=\frac{FX}{XA}.$$